# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - Latest changes to toppager_right do not support backward competability

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I replaced the jqGrid I had with the latest one from GIT (4.9.0 beta something), and the toppager_right is now defaulted as "display: none;"

That basically makes what I had there not visible.

I had this $(nameOfGrid + '_toppager_right').append(indication); used for painting some specific html code (marked here as 'indication'), but now I can't get it due to last changes.

Is there a new way to use _toppager_right? or  should I just change the element using Jquery (doing $(nameOfGrid + '_toppager_right').show() will solve this,just that I still think this is a backward compatibility issue that might need to be mentioned)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is new option `hideEmptyPagerParts` of `navGrid`. It will be set to `true` by default. The option allows to save place in pager. The pager consist typically from parts: left, center and right. All what the option `hideEmptyPagerParts: true` do is examining of the parts and calling `.hide()` to save place in the pager.

So you have the following alternatives:

1. you can specify `navOptions: { hideEmptyPagerParts: false }` of the grid or to add `hideEmptyPagerParts: false` to the list of options of `navGrid` which you use.
2. You can place some information in the right pager **before** call of `navGrid`. For example you can use `$(nameOfGrid + "toppager_right").append("<span></span>");` which add *empty* `<span>`. It will makes the right pager non-empty and it will be not hidden more.
3. You can add `$(nameOfGrid + '_toppager_right').show();` after you set the custom "indicator" information in the right pager. It will make the part of pager visible.

Any from the above ways should solve your problem.